# How works Image scale with device scale

Tags: ios, image

I try to understand how images are rendering on devices with the different scale of **device and image**. 
We have image 100x100px if we set image scale to x2, 1 user point will be 2px, so image size will be 50x50 points on device screen with x2 scale(iphone7) and on x3 scale(ipxoneX) why?
How is this working? Will be very thankful for detailed explanation

Comment: please check this apple's documentation : https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/

Comment: I saw this guid, but still not understand my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we have is image, buffer and coordinate system. Image has its size, buffer has its size and coordinate system may have it.

The scales were introduced in context of coordinate system and buffers when retina displays bace a thing. Basically we used to develop for solid 320x480 coordinate systems which was also the size of a buffer and so a 320x480 image was drawn exactly as full screen perfectly.

Then retina displays suddenly made devices 2x resulting in 640x960 buffers. If there was no scale then all the hardcoded values (we used to have) would produce a messed up layout. So Apple persisted the coordinate system at 320x480 and introduced scale which basically means that `UIKit` frame-related logic stayed the same. From developer perspective all that changed is that @2x image would initialize a half smaller image view when initialized with image from assets. So a 512x512 image would produce a 256x256 image view using `UIImageView(image: myImage)`.

Now we have quite a lot more then 320x480 and their multipliers and use auto-layout. We have 1x, 2x and 3x and we may get 10x for what e care in the future (probably not going to happen due to limitations of our eyes). And these scales are here actually so that all devices have similar PPI (points per inch) where these points are considered in coordinate system. What that means is that if you place a button with height of 50px it will physically produce similar height on all devices no matter the scale.

So what does all of this have to do with rendering an image? Well, nothing actually. The scale is just a converter between your coordinate system and your buffer. So at scale of 2x if you in code (or IB) create a 50x50 image view you can expect it's buffer to be 100x100. Ergo if you want the image to look nice you should use a 100x100 image. But since you want to do it for all the relevant scales you should have 3 images 50x50, 100x100 and 150x150 and naming them same with suffixing `@2x` and `@3x` you will ensure that `UIImage(name:)` will use correct image depending on current device scale.

So to your question directly:

*if we set image scale to x2, 1 user point will be 2px, so image size will be 50x50*: You usually don't set a scale of an image. `UIImage` is a wrapper of `CGImage` which will always have direct size. `UIImage` uses its orientation and scale to transform that size. But if you mean you are setting a 100x100 image with @2x then on 2x devices an image view initialized with this image will have a size of 50x50 which is coordinate system but would be drawn to a 100x100 buffer as it is.

It really might be hard to explain this but the key you are looking for is that coordinate system has a scale toward display resolution (rather toward used buffer). If it did not we would need to increase everything on devices with higher resolution; If we put 2 devices together with same physical size (lets say 320x480) of the screen where first had 1x and second 2x resolution then all components would be half the size on the second: An icon of 32x32 would take 10% of width on 1x and 5% on 2x. So to simulate the same physical size we actually need 64x64 icon but then we also need to set the frame to 64x64. We would also need to use larger font sizes or all the texts would suddenly be very small...

*I try to understand how images are rendering on devices with the different scale of device and image.*: There is no "scale" in concept between *device and image*. Device (in this case a display screen) will receive a buffer of pixels that it needs to draw. This buffer will be of appropriate size for it so we are only talking about rendering image on this buffer. Image may be rendered through `UIKit` on this buffer any way you want; If you want you can draw a 400x230 image to 100x300 part of a buffer. But optimally a 400x230 image will be drawn to 400x230 part of the buffer meaning it was not magnified, shrunk or otherwise transformed. So assuming:

- image size: 64x64 (actual image pixels)
- `UIView` size: 320x320 (.frame.size)
- `UIView` scale: 2x
- Icon size: 32x32 (UIImageView.frame.size)
- Buffer size: 640x640 (size of the actual buffer on which the image will be drawn)
- `UIImage` size: 32x32 (.size you get from loaded image)
- `UIImage` scale: 2x (.scale you get from loaded image)

Now from buffer perspective you are drawing 64x64 image to 640x640 buffer which takes 10% of the buffer per dimension. And from coordinate system perspective you are drawing 32x32 image to 320x320 canvas which takes 10% of the canvas per dimension.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I need to think about all of this

Comment: but if we draw image 32x32px with scale x3 to buffer 640x640 and 320x320 points, does it mean that from buffer perspective we will draw 96x96p wich takes 15% or 48 points on user points ?

Comment: @YuriyFedchenko Well no matter the image size but if we use UIView coordinates to draw to 32x32 part of the view having x3 scale then the destination buffer will be filled as 96x96. If that is on 640x640 buffer it means 15%. But what are user points? That is usually still 96 points on device (96 dots if you look under microscope). And to draw the image perfectly you would need to have original image of size 96x96 but loaded as UIImage it would say 32x32 with scale of 3.